# Unity terrain - build terrain from google maps

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am brand new to Unity, but I was wondering if there is a way to create terrain by somehow capturing a piece of Google Earth, and somehow exporting it to the engine's terrain editor? If there isn't a direct way of doing this, could someone suggest the best way to go about copying a portion of Google Earth (or something similar) to build a terrain?

Comment: This tool claims to be able to export heightmaps from Google Maps: http://terrain.party/ .  Using that, I think you should be able to import the heightmap into Unity in some way to generate your terrain.

Comment: Thats an awesome tool, i will give it a try. thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Josh1billion the answer seems to be [terrain.party](http://terrain.party/), here is a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-vyNbalvXR4) link that expands on it

Answer (score 0):

For completion, a pricy tool that does most of the work for you:
Real World Terrain: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/real-world-terrain-8752
It has good reviews.

If you are serious about it, keep in mind that AAA titles build worlds still manualy from reference pictures.

Hey dreamer (or) If you want to change industry:

Good base data from goverment (swiss only) costs between few 100k up to 2M, while free to students.
Heigh educated knowledge of AI, software engineering and some math required. Hudge manpower needed. Buildings are the biggest problem.